# Изменение коллекции DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

Имеется DataGridView. Одна из колонок должна иметь только определённые значения, ей присвоен тип DataGridViewTextBoxColumn и задана определённая коллекция (Items) например (работа 1, работа 2, работа 3, работа 4).
Можно ли как то к этой колонке привязать ещё одну коллекцию с другими работами, или что бы отображалась только часть работ из первоначального списка.
Например, в Понедельник мы отображаем в combobox только работу 1 и работу 2, а во вторник работу 3 и работу 4.
DataGridView создавался в конструкторе, соответственно код есть только в Desigrer.cs[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Частично решил вопрос.
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ourColumn =
dataGridViewWork.Columns[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V6fH.jpg) as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;

Теперь могу добавлять коллекцию
ourColumn.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"работа 5", "работа 6"});

Теперь очищаю её, что бы заполнить новыми значениями           ourColumn.Items.Clear();
и следовательно вылетает ошибка, ибо есть уже заполненные ячейки старыми значениями, как их сохранить?

Comment: Покажите скриншот хотя-бы, со слов пока не до конца не понятно. Коллекция у вас `BindingList`? Покажите код класса, который является типом элементов этой коллекции, и код, в котором вы создаете, заполняете и привязываете коллекцию к таблице.

Comment: Какая именно ошибка? Покажите ее текст

Comment: Суть проблемы понятна, но без кода сложно понять как вам можно помочь. Я бы посоветовал использовать dataGridView только для отображения данных, а оформлять заявку в отдельной форме с combobox'ом. Открывая форму с заявкой, этот combobox, можете заполнять как хотите, а dgv не будет содержать никаких коллекций, только выбранное значение и ошибок никаких не будет.

Comment: @aepot Ошибка system argumentnullexception:Недопустимое значение DataGridViewComboBoxCell. На каждую строчку где были значения из старой коллекции.

Comment: @Михаил В отдельной форме неудобно. Тем более я делаю аналог софтины начала девяностых, написанной хз на чём, ею пользуемся до сих пор, часть функций не работает и нужны новые. В старой программе это реализовано так как я описал) Если в 90ые кто то проблему решил, значит в 2020 это тоже реально) Правда я 3 месяца назад никакого отношения к программированию. не имел, а теперь появилось желание попробовать себя в этом)

Comment: Аналог софтины начала девяностых это конечно хорошо, но как Вы сами сказали, Вы не имеете понятия, какие технологии использовались при её создании. Да и за последние 30 лет подходы к разработке ПО сильно поменялись. Боюсь, что для реализации Вашей задачи, потребуется переопределять контрол dgv и добавлять какое-то сокрытие для item'ом Вашего списка, а это не самая простая задача. Не думаю, что с Вас прям требуют полный аналог софтины, а доп. форма, как правило, весьма гармонично вписывается в дизайн ПО. Но решать конечно же Вам.